# List comprehension putting Boolean's inside of list instead of integers

Tags: python, python-2.7

I made a list comprehension to only add numbers less than or equal to 5 to b, but when I run my program it outputs Boolean's instead of integers.

How do I change them to integers.

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
b = [i <= 5 for i in a]
print b

[True, True, True, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: You are asking python to check whether or not each entry in a is less than or equal to 5. So python is populating b with the answer. Check out Keiwan's answer for the correct way to accomplish your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the correct way to achieve what you want:

```
b = [i for i in a if i <= 5]
```

Your version is putting the result of the expression `i <= 5` - which is a boolean - into the list for every element in `a`, no matter what the outcome of the comparison is.